# Template Lib (Engine) in Python running with Jython

Tags: python, jython, template-engine

Im searching a Template Lib or Template Engine for generating HTML (XML) that runs under Jython (Jython 2.5 Alpha is ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use StringTemplate, see http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf for details of why.  There is nothing better, and it supports both Java and Python (and .NET, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/), I don't have direct experience running it under Jython but there seem to be some people that do.

Answer (score 2):

Jinja is pretty cool and seems to work on Jython.