# Cannot install jinja2 with jython pip?

Tags: jinja2, jython, jython-2.7

I am using Windows 7 with Jython 2.7.0.  I am able to run `jython --version` and `pip --version` in the bin directory and get back what I expect, 2.7.0 and 1.6, with a bunch of extra information.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\myUser>cd ../..

C:\>cd jython2.7.0/bin

C:\jython2.7.0\bin>pip --version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.python.core.PySystemState (file:/C:/jy
thon2.7.0/jython.jar) to method java.io.Console.encoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.python.core.Py
SystemState
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflect
ive access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Feb 16, 2021 1:37:50 PM org.python.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent <clinit
>
INFO: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct
 buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be prefe
rred to avoid potential system unstability.
pip 1.6.dev1 from C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

I try to install jinja2 with `pip install jinja2` and have also tried it captialized since I saw that as well `pip install Jinja2` and get the following

```
C:\jython2.7.0\bin>pip install jinja2
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.python.core.PySystemState (file:/C:/jy
thon2.7.0/jython.jar) to method java.io.Console.encoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.python.core.Py
SystemState
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflect
ive access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Feb 16, 2021 1:44:35 PM org.python.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent <clinit
>
INFO: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct
 buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be prefe
rred to avoid potential system unstability.
Downloading/unpacking jinja2
Got this failure javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch! during SSL handshake
(<_realsocket at 0x215 type=client open_count=1 channel=[id: 0x53d8a502, /192.16
8.1.59:64975 => pypi.python.org/199.232.36.223:443] timeout=15.0>)
Got this failure javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch! during SSL handshake
(<_realsocket at 0x216 type=client open_count=1 channel=[id: 0x3d4b1e67, /192.16
8.1.59:64976 :> pypi.python.org/199.232.36.223:443] timeout=15.0>)
←[31m  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
←[0mGot this failure javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch! during SSL handsh
ake (<_realsocket at 0x217 type=client open_count=1 channel=[id: 0x5f10319d, /19
2.168.1.59:64977 :> pypi.python.org/199.232.36.223:443] timeout=15.0>)
←[31m  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement jinja2
←[0mCleaning up...
←[31mNo distributions at all found for jinja2
←[0m←[31mStoring debug log for failure in C:\Users\bkarabinchak\.pip\pip.log
←[0m
```

This line `←[31mNo distributions at all found for jinja2` makes me think there is no Jinja2 for jython, nor Cheetah which I also tried to install.  I tried those as they were referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157313/template-lib-engine-in-python-running-with-jython) as jython HTML Templaters.

Can someone either 1) Help me troubleshoot installing jinja2 or 2) Recommend a HTML Template package that does exist for jython if jinja2/Cheetah do no work?

Comment: I would try Jython 2.7.2, which is the latest version (released in 2020).

Comment: I got windows 7 so 2.7.0 is the max I can use :/ however I am getting a new laptop in a few weeks that is windows 10 and so at that point I can use a more recent jython.  I'll just put a pin in this until then.  Thanks.